# Would it be appropriate to ask a Meta question about favorite HR sites for information?

Tags: discussion, meta, community-wiki

As we well know, making a good hardware recommendation basically involves a skilled search of a very large problem space with plenty of uncertainty for everyone save the eidetically-gifted. I was wondering if it would be proper for us to question our community about what sites they use to help them navigate this search space; for example, I'm a really big fan of the following aids:

- http://www.passmark.com/
- http://pcpartpicker.com/
- https://pchound.com/3Qye6z/
- http://www.cpu-world.com/
- http://www.newegg.com/
- http://www.userbenchmark.com/

Answer (score 1):

**I don't see any reason why not.**

There are no policies that this goes against in particular, and it could lead to a useful list of resources that we could also link to in our FAQs and potentially the help center.

I would suggest that it's done so we have one website per answer, instead of one list-answer per user - that would end up giving us better detail on each site, which is important if we want to point people to it and say "try these things".

Comment: I agree to the "one website per answer" format concept.